# How delete \r\n in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

error: undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass

```rb
                                "updated_at" => "",
                                 "fias_ao_guid" => "\r\n",
                                    "file_path" => nil
```

how delete "\r\n"?

```rb
             splitted_records = []
      id = 3141634
      string = 0
      row = 0
      h = {}
      record_candidate = {}
      open('/home/dayanov-sa/PGadmin/finish.csv') do |csv|
         csv.each_line do |line|
            index = 0
            row += 1
               line.split(";").each do |key_filed|
                record_candidate["#{key_filed.delete("\r\n")}"] = nil
               end if row.eql?(1)
            next if row.eql?(1)
            copy_object = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(line))
            values = line.split(";")
            record_candidate.keys.each do |keys|
               index += 1
               record_candidate[keys] = values[index].delete("\r\n")
               end
            id = id + 1
            puts string
            splitted_records << record_candidate
```

I'm trying to remove from the hash \ r \ n

Comment: Obviously `record_candidate` has more keys than `line` has values, but it's hard to suggest anything without more context.

Comment: @Vasfed i update

Comment: Please describe original problem you're solving (along with example input and desired output data), from above I can tell that it's some csv parsing - and ruby already has csv parser in stdlib

Comment: @Vasfed the problem is that I cannot delete the value "\ r \ n", it gives an error with the words: undefined method `delete 'for nil: NilClass

Comment: Looks like XY Problem - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: To remove line endings, there's [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-chomp) and to parse CSVs, there [`CSV`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html). Don't reinvent the wheel ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of some hash keys have `nil` values e.g. ("file_path" => `nil`)

You need to bypass the `nil` values

Your code will be like this:

```rb
record_candidate.keys.each do |keys|
  index += 1
  if !values[index].nil?
     record_candidate[keys] = values[index].delete("\r\n")
  end
end
```

Comment: yes, i change: ```ruby record_candidate[keys] = values[index].delete("\r\n") if values[index].present? ```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like an attempt to parse CSV with a header. Ruby already has that in stdlib:

```rb
require 'csv'

file_contents = File.read('/home/dayanov-sa/PGadmin/finish.csv')
data = CSV.parse(file_contents, headers: true, col_sep: ';')
splitted_records = data.map(&:to_h)
```

see [ruby documentation on CSV](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

Comment: Thank u! I have a large file and it hangs. Therefore, I do line by line